# Markdown viewer for Android

Tags: android, open-source, markdown

I am looking for a Markdown viewer for Android. It should:

run locally on Android- be a normal app, not a browser addon, webapp or anything else that requires usage of the browser.

Preferable:

- simple and lightweight
- open-source or premium
- Viewer as in "view formatted content", Markdown as in CommonMark.

Comment: So it must be a "plain viewer" – and [markdown editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_107) are out of the equation? How do you define "lightweight"? From its description, [Notes](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.billthefarmer.notes/) might fit the bill: only 200k …

Comment: Yes it should be plain viewer, the editor is optional

Comment: Optional means it would be acceptable – then the mentioned "Notes" app should be worth a look. As I've not used it myself, I can only argue by description & screenshots – so feel free to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if it fits. All the best!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [JotterPad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x&hl=en), it's a MarkDown editor but does viewing superbly. I love it's dark mode. I think it might work for you, give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zettel Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.eu.thedoc.zettelnotes). The UI so fast and have so many feature.

Comment: Can you add some detail about its main features and how it complies with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [markor](https://github.com/gsantner/markor),Notes. The UI so fast and have so many feature.